# `order by` et `group` by in an `inner join` SQLite query

Tags: sqlite, join, group-by, sql-order-by

Considering below SQLite DB tables and this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s3_NMjz5):

**`events` table**

```
id   | text
---------
id_1 | hello
id_2 | world
```

**`calendar` table**

```
id   | start
---------------
id_1 | 2023-01-01
id_1 | 2023-06-01
id_1 | 2023-09-01
id_1 | 2023-10-01
id_2 | 2023-05-01
id_2 | 2023-08-29
id_2 | 2023-10-30
id_2 | 2023-11-30
```

How do I simply get a list of all next coming `events` ordered by `calendar.start`?
Utimately, I'll add some `where` clause on `events` table (e.g. `where status = 'published'`)

I tried:

```
select * from events
inner join calendar using (id)
where calendar.start > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
group by id
```

But I'm struggling with the `order by` (cannot be after `group by` or before). I tried with a `min` but it seems complicated. Should I go with [`distinct`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) on `calendar` table? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get a list of all next coming events ordered by calendar.start

Based on my understanding of what you want to achieve, you should not use group by. Group By are for aggregating data such as counting the number of columns or adding a column together.

Your statement would only return 2 rows (i.e. the number of events which is 2 according to your table.

```
select * from events
inner join calendar using (id)
where calendar.start > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
ORDER BY calendar.start
```

will give you a list of calendars associated with reoccurring events

i.e.

```
id      text    start
--------------------------
id_2    world   2023-08-29
id_1    hello   2023-09-01
id_1    hello   2023-10-01
id_2    world   2023-10-30
id_2    world   2023-11-30
```

Group by as I mentioned earlier is to aggregate rows (at least it usually is). For instance, let's grab the number of meetups for each event remaining:

```
select calendar.id, events.text, count(*) as num_events_remaining
from events
inner join calendar using (id)
where calendar.start > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
group by id
```

which results:

```
id      text    num_events_remaining
------------------------------------
id_1    hello   2
id_2    world   3
```

**Edit:**

If you want a table that grabs the next upcoming meeting for each event, the SQL query, then you are correct to use `group by`. I should have caught what you were trying to do when you said you experimented with `min`.

```
SELECT id, text, min(start) AS upcoming 
FROM calendar 
INNER JOIN events using (id)
WHERE calendar.start > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY upcoming
```

Would give you:

```
id      text    upcoming
--------------------------
id_2    world   2023-08-29
id_1    hello   2023-09-01
```

Similarly if you want the last meeting for each event,  you would use `max`:

```
SELECT id, text, max(start) AS last_date 
FROM calendar 
INNER JOIN events using (id)
WHERE calendar.start > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY last_date
```

which gives you:

```
id      text    last_date
--------------------------
id_1    hello   2023-10-01
id_2    world   2023-11-30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand. However, at the end, I'd like a query result to be (distinct): `id_2`, `id_1`, because, in plain english: the first next upcoming event is `id_2` (because one of its occurrence is 2023-08-29, and after it's `id_1` (because the first next occurrence is 2023-09-01). Any idea?

Comment: Maybe try: ```SELECT id, text, min(start) AS upcoming 
FROM calendar 
INNER JOIN events using (id)
WHERE calendar.start > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY upcoming``` Edit: I see why you used `group by` now, you wanted to use `min` which you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Perfect! It works. But is it efficient/fast in a huge DB (theory)?

Comment: I am no database expert but I would assume a database like SQLite would have no issues going through millions of records with this SQL command. The query is quite simple with just one join and provided you have `id` as an indexable column ~and start set with the type `date` if it exists in SQLite,~ should be  efficient. You could try using `explain` command to see what the database is doing.